# How to make a type T that `std::is_empty_v<T> && sizeof(T) > 1` is true?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I came across an interesting quiz question at [here](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/10/29/cppcon-2021-pub-quiz-2/):

> Write a translation unit containing a class type T, such that
> `std::is_empty_v<T>` is true, and yet `sizeof(T)` is greater than 1.

I'v thought about it for some time, but no solution.

How to make a type `T` that `std::is_empty_v<T> && sizeof(T) > 1` is true?

Comment: Can you specialize `std::is_empty<T>` for your type? That would be one way to lie.

Comment: class S { char c[2]; }; template<> struct std::is_empty<S> : std::true_type { }; You didn't say it should be valid C++ :P

Comment: @TanveerBadar That's undefined.

Comment: @Mestkon By that reasoning every "how can I [something]?" question could be answered by "try UB, maybe it'll work for you?".

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Technically they all can :P. But still, it was a quiz, and quizzes aren't always looking for a proper answer. They can include trick questions and stuff like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::is_empty` checks if there are no members. You can use alignment to force a size greater than 1:

```cpp
struct alignas(2) T {};

static_assert(std::is_empty_v<T>);
static_assert(sizeof(T) > 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since two identical empty classes cannot share the same address, we can create a class that inherits an empty base and also has an empty base as a member to prohibit EBO and make its size greater than `1`.

```
#include<type_traits>

struct B { };
struct D : B { [[no_unique_address]] B b; };

static_assert(std::is_empty_v<D> && sizeof(D) > 1);
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/j1j7K9Yra)

Comment: The answer would be improved if you added an explanation of why you've used inheritance, and [[no_unique_address]] and how that solves the problem.